# gradle maven ssh

Tags: maven, gradle

I'm using the "mavenDeployer" to use ssh/scp during "uploadArchives" task,
with the wagon ssh utilities.

Rather than code a password into the build.gradle, I'd like to rely on proper ssh setup. Specifically, I want to have the user specify their private key, and have that private key loaded in their environment (ssh-agent, ssh-add, etc). The maven repo has a shared userid,
and all real users have their .pub key properly added to the "authorized_keys" file
of shared userid.

Although maven/ant seem to have a "privateKey" attribute, and the Gradle DSL
accepts it, it doesn't seem to have any effect when I set it:

```
        mavenDeployer {
            configuration = pr.configurations.publishJars
            String keyFile = System.properties["user.mavenKey"]
            repository(url: "scp://maven.company.com/path/to/maven") {
                    logger.info("Using SSH key: ${keyFile}")
                    authentication(userName: "maven", privateKey: keyFile)
            }
```

If I code in the actual password as per the example in gradle documentation, 
it does work, so I know that things are working. Also, changing privateKey 
to privatekey (all lower case) causes a property error, so I know the 
property exists and is recognized at some level.

And I know the ssh key itself is working:

```
  % ssh -i ~/.ssh/mavenKey maven@maven.company.com ls /
  [ no errors, output trimmed ]
```

But when I run it, I get prompted for shared userid's password:

```
  % gradle uploadArchives
  [... stuff ...]
  Using SSH key: /homes/klash/.ssh/mavenKey
  Password for maven@evomaven.englab.juniper.net:
```

As you can see, it is NOT prompting for passphrase for the key.

Comment: `Using SSH key: /homes/klash/.ssh/mavenKey` Isn't there a typo in your System property? Should probably be `/home/klash/...`

Comment: No, there is no typo. Our home dirs are on NFS, via auto-mount, typical big-tech company set-up. I've quadruple-checked that what is getting passed is a correct path to SSH private key.

Comment: Can't see any problems with your code, I'm basically doing the same thing with no problems. Which gradle version are you using? Have you tried running with '-d' flag (it produces _a lot_ of output, but can be helpful when trying to understand what's happening). Another thing; you mention the ssh passphrase - is such passphrase required in your set up? That would be a difference from what I've tested since my ssh private key does not have a passphrase.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your private key doesn't require a pass phrase.
Can you access the remote from command line using ssh maven@evomaven.englab.juniper.net without being prompted for password?
If not use ssh-copy-id to send your public key to the server.